# Starting a java swing process on boot using Upstart -- No X11 DISPLAY variable was set

Tags: java, linux, swing, x11, upstart

I have a runnable jar file produced from clojure code that I am running on an embedded system (udoo - http://www.udoo.org/), which is running a version of Ubuntu for its OS (udoobuntu - http://www.udoo.org/udoobuntu-the-official-udoo-linux-operating-system/).

The jar file contains a clojure library I wrote, that includes a some Java swing stuff.

Running the jar manually via the command line using:
    sudo java -jar myjar.jar
works fine.  The sudo is needed for certain usb device permissions.

My problem arises when I try to start the jar using an upstart script called testjob.  The relevant part of /etc/init/testjob.conf looks like:

```
start on (desktop-session-start)

expect fork

script
        exec ./home/ubuntu/start > /home/ubuntu/boot-jar.log 2>&1 &
end script
```

Where /home/ubuntu/start is the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh 
sudo java -jar /home/ubuntu/myjar.jar
exit 0
```

When this runs, either manually via:
    sudo start testjob
or automatically by rebooting the system, I get the following output to the log file:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

... <bunch of meaningless classloading stuff>

Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException:
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
    at sun.awt.HeadlessToolkit.getMenuShortcutKeyMask(HeadlessToolkit.java:236)
    at seesaw.keystroke$preprocess_descriptor.invoke(keystroke.clj:25)
    at seesaw.keystroke$keystroke.invoke(keystroke.clj:50)
    at seesaw.keystroke$keystroke.invoke(keystroke.clj:49)
    at seesaw.keymap$map_key.doInvoke(keymap.clj:107)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:445)
    at seesaw.widgets.log_window$log_window.doInvoke(log_window.clj:88)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:457)
    at physicloud.utils__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at physicloud.utils__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 52 more
```

I don't actually make any UI calls, but the run fails on classloading of the library.  I know that a simple fix would be to remove the Java Swing code from the library, but the library is generalized to allow ui output to capable machines, and therefore I am looking for a workaround.  It doesn't make sense to me why the jar will run via java -jar but not in the script.

I tried different cases for the upstart script's "start on" condition, all of which produced the same result.

I tried setting the $DISPLAY environment variable in the upstart script before executing the jar, but to no avail.

I also tried scheduling the start script using crontab @reboot, but the error was the same.

Anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Don't use sudo to deal with permission problems. By sudo-ing your process you make it run as root and should your program get cracked, and have a remote code execution vulnerability, your system is immediately compromised., Instead add the user running the program into a dedicated group and add a udev rule to give that group access to the USB devices in question.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `-Djava.awt.headless=true` to `java` to allow running non-GUI applications that happen to depend on some UI libraries.

For example,

```
java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar something.jar
```

Comment: Sorry I actually tried this as well and forgot to mention it.  In fact, when I pass that JVM option, my jar no longer even works using java -jar xxx.jar and it throws a 'java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError, Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException'

Comment: Are you sure the jar doesn't try to open a window or query the display? If it does anything like that you'd have to either wait until X starts (if enabled on boot), or start your own xfb or vnc server for it to work with